# Copy values from a SubClass to SuperClass java

Tags: java, inheritance, apache-commons

I have 2 interface like this

```
public interface Super {
    void setA();
    Long getA();
}

public interface Sub extends Super{

}
```

Now 2 classes which are implementing these

```
public class AStore implements Super {
    Long A;
}

public class BStore implements Sub{
    LongA;
}
```

Now at some moment if i use Apache library

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(Sub, Super);
```

it works
but not the reverse

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(Super, Sub);
```

Is there anyway or any other library through which i can copy the values from Sub to Super?

Comment: Do you mean it works from `BStore` to `AStore` and not the reverse? And BTW, why does `BStore` not extend `AStore`? Is there a reason?

Comment: No i meant between Sub and Super only. And AStore is not extending BStore as i didn't want their implementation to be same.

Comment: But `Super` and `Sub` are interfaces. What are the concrete classes that you used? It can only be `AStore` and `BStore`.

Comment: lets take it this way
Super super = new AStore();
Sub sub = new BStore();
sub.setA(12L);

now i want to copy the values to super.

Comment: Another approach would be the usage of a custom mapper, converter.

Comment: Can't reproduce. You may need to post a complete, real example, showing your getters and setters too

Comment: I just made a test, cannot reproduce either.